# Django debug toolbar works only in admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar

I've did all the steps which are described in the docs and got the toolbar in admin site. However, I can't get it work in the project frontend side.
Here is my settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'debug_toolbar',
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
]


INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1', 'localhost',)
```

I've googled a lot already and non of the proposed solution are not working for me: workaround that shows toolbar even if `debug=False`, playing with different parameters like `INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS=False/True`, specifying `JQUERY_URL` since there is a local jquery which is used by frontend. 
I've asked for help from frontend dev, but he can't understand why there is no any configs for client side. 
Frontend is using nodes.js and listens on 3000 port than forwards to localhost:8081.

Django version 1.10, django-debug-toolbar 1.9.1.

Comment: Sometimes order of middleware(`'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware'`) matters put it top of the list and try.

Comment: @N.HariHaraSudhan just tried - didn't help.

Comment: `if settings.DEBUG:
  import debug_toolbar
  urlpatterns =[
         url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
         ] + urlpatterns` did u add this in `urls.py`

Comment: @N.HariHaraSudhan yes, I did, with the only difference that it goes right before project's urls, so project's url adds to that.

Answer (score 0):

according to [doc](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) you must add another url in your main urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path("__debug__/", include("debug_toolbar.urls")),
]
```